# How to sum TIME in MySQL

Tags: mysql, time

I was using `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time)))` combination, but it can sum up to 24 hours. I am not able to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` because it cannot be invoked with `TIME`. How can I achieve it then?

I want my sum looks like that:

`120:59:30.000`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Once you've summed your times, diff them with zero time i.e. `TIMEDIFF('00:00:00', summedTimes)` to get the result. No dates are needed with this method (although `TIMEDIFF` can take both `TIME` and `DATETIME` formats as inputs)